# How can i change the colour of the details-control classname icon

Tags: jquery, datatables

How can I change the color of the details-control class icon: before to blue,
as we see when we make a datatable as responsive.
I am using https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/row_details.html,

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

var table_data = [{"name":"Tiger Nixon","position":"System Architect","salary":"$320,800","start_date":"2011/04/25","office":"Edinburgh","extn":"5421"},{"name":"Garrett Winters","position":"Accountant","salary":"$170,750","start_date":"2011/07/25","office":"Tokyo","extn":"8422"},{"name":"Ashton Cox","position":"Junior Technical Author","salary":"$86,000","start_date":"2009/01/12","office":"San Francisco","extn":"1562"}];

var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "data": table_data,
    "columns": [
        {
            "className":      'details-control',
            "orderable":      false,
            "data":           null,
            "defaultContent": ''
        },
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "position" },
        { "data": "office" },
        { "data": "salary" }
    ],
    "order": [[1, 'asc']]
} );
 
// Add event listener for opening and closing details
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row( tr );

    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
        tr.removeClass('highlightExpanded');
    }
    else {
        // Open this row
        row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
        tr.addClass('highlightExpanded');
    }
} );
} );
```

Comment: The class `td.details-control` uses a background image for the plus and minus icons. Change that backogrund image to one that suits your needs

Comment: even if i change the url for the icon, it turns back to the same old icon.

Comment: That doesnt sound right. It's a simple class for which they used inline css to stlye the element with a background image. You can name the class however you want and therefore style the element however you want. Have another look at the JS and CSS code they provide on the page you posted